# It is safe to keep the glue residues on the motherboard that had a backplate

Tags: motherboard, cooling

This might seem a stupid question but i just want to be sure.

Some cooler have a backplate with sticky (really sticky!) edge on back of them in order
to stick it on the motherboard. I removed mine with a lots of force but at least i removed it.

However, there are some left glue residues on the motherboard.. that would be pain to remove ! personnally i don't really care if they are
keep there but it is safe ?

http://cdn.overclock.net/0/0d/600x450px-LL-0dba8363_Pic1.jpeg (sorry the integrated pic fonction seemed to not work i can't see the pic otherwise)

[image: backplate risidues]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adhesives generally used for this are non-conductive and non-corrosive, so leaving it on is fine.

Answer (score 9):

If having the glue connect the motherboard to a big conductive plate wasn't a problem, the glue by itself won't be a problem either.

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot like typical double sided tape. The portion in question looks like the X shaped mechanical support, rather than a heat sink unit. I'm rather doubtful that it would make a difference to do with heat transfer to the motherboard, or any other cooling relatd process. I do worry it would be a dust magnet, which would be bad.

If you do want to remove it, you can probably very gently loosen it up with a lit free cloth and isopryl alcohol. Rub to 'roll' it into a larger wad, and periodically remove it.

Comment: Tried.. trust me lol anyway i prefer to lets it there since there another backplate going on so it doesn't matter i guess.

Comment: better than alcohol is carburetor cleaner. It takes that glue right off and evaporates instantly. Small amounts will do no harm to your mobo, just don't soak the thing down.

Comment: Well, i trust rubbing alcohol and elbow grease to do nothing. Nail polish remover to me, is the next step up. Never used carburetor cleaner before.